# Puppeteer - browser.pages()

Tags: javascript, python, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I am running await browser.pages() in puppeteer (pyppeteer), however every time it is run, my browser pages go to a very small window size.
Is there any way to avoid this? I am for example scanning every 1s to evaluate all browser URLs, and obviously the browser is unusable with such a small window size.
If I drag and drop the browser across the screen, the full window size returns so it is a bit of an odd issue.
I am using pyppeteer.connect.

```
async def main():
    browser = await pyppeteer.connect(browserURL='http://127.0.0.1:9222')
    pages = browser.pages()

    print(pages)
    i = 0

    print(len(pages))
    while i < len(pages):
        print(await pages[i].evaluate("() => window.location.href"))
        i = i + 1
```

Alternatively, are there any other easy ways to get all open browser URLs?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! `while` is very awkward for counters. Why not use a `for` loop, like `for page in pages: print(await page.evaluate(...))`?

Answer (score 2):

when you connect ,set this

```
 defaultViewport: null,
```